# Multistep Node Form

Tags: 7, forms

Are there any examples of creating a multistep NODE form. I looked at the examples module, but there was only a regular multistep form.

What I am looking to do is have a spreadsheet be uploaded and parsed which then creates a 2nd step in the form which populates a field collection w/ unlimited cardinality of field of type/name.

Could this be done with AJAX instead? (Drupal 7.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with a regular multistep form, and create your node in the final submit function.

Answer (score 0):

The [Multistep module](http://drupal.org/project/multistep) does this to node create/edit forms (and only to node create/edit forms, in fact). It saves the data entered on each step when the step is submitted, so if the process is interrupted the node is still created and can be further filled-in later.